# How to make width/height of stage flexible/auto fit in flash?

Tags: flash, stage

In flex the `width` can be set to `100%`,but in flash it seems I can only set the `width/height` in unit of `px`.

Is there a way to set the stage to `100%` instead of `xxx px` in flash?

I'm using Flash Professional CS5 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/liquid_gui.html

Comment: Link is outdated. Try Google Cache  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/flash/articles/liquid_gui.html